# What causes the problem: csv, pandas or nltk?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nltk

I have a strange problem resulting in wrong output delivered by NLTK collocations. In short, when I pass pandas object created in python envi (PyCharm or Jupyter) to the function I get correct result. When I save this object to csv and upload it to the pandas object, functions returns single letters and/or numbers instead of full words. Must be sth wrong with csv upload through pandas but I have no idea what is wrong...

here is the code.

Function that is applied:

```
def counts(x):
    trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
    finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_documents(x)
    finder.nbest(trigram_measures.pmi, 100)

    s = pd.Series(x)
    ngram_list = [pair for row in s for pair in ngrams(row, 3)]
    c = Counter(ngram_list).most_common(3)

    return pd.DataFrame([(x.name, ) + element for element in c], columns=['group', 'Ngram', 'Frequency'])
```

Here is the object:

```
d = {'words' : pd.Series((['coffee', 'maker', 'brewing', 'properly', '2', '420', '420', '420'],
    ['galley', 'work', 'table', 'stuck'],
    ['cloth', 'stuck'],
    ['stuck', 'coffee'])),
    'group' : pd.Series([1, 2, 1, 2])}
df_cleaned = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Then I apply function from above + some extra functions:

```
output = df_cleaned.groupby('group', as_index=False).words.apply(counts).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result is correct:

[image]

But when pandas object is saved and uploaded result is sth like this:

here is a code for saving and uploading:

```
df.to_csv('test_file.csv', index=False, sep=',')

df = pd.read_csv('path/test_file.csv',
sep=',', usecols=['group','words'])
```

I found quotes in uploaded pandas object therefore I had removed them before applying the fucntion"

```
df = df.replace({'\'': ''}, regex=True)

output = df_cleaned.groupby('group', as_index=False).words.apply(counts).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now it returns wrong results.

[image]

Do have any suggestions which way shall I go?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced what you described in the following steps. I don't see any errors

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'words' : pd.Series((['coffee', 'maker', 'brewing', 'properly', '2','420', '420', '420'],
    ['galley', 'work', 'table', 'stuck'],
    ['cloth', 'stuck'],
    ['stuck', 'coffee'])),
    'group' : pd.Series([1, 2, 1, 2])}
df_cleaned = pd.DataFrame(d)
df_cleaned
```

The function you're using is

```
import nltk
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk.collocations import *
from collections import Counter
def counts(x):
    trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
    finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_documents(x)
    finder.nbest(trigram_measures.pmi, 100)
    s = pd.Series(x)
    ngram_list = [pair for row in s for pair in ngrams(row, 3)]
    c = Counter(ngram_list).most_common(3)
    return pd.DataFrame([(x.name, ) + element for element in c], columns=['group', 'Ngram', 'Frequency'])
```

You then apply `counts` to the data

```
output = df_cleaned.groupby('group', 
            as_index=False).words.apply(counts).reset_index(drop=True)
```

and save the results to file

```
output.to_csv('test_file.csv', index=False, sep=',')
df = pd.read_csv('test_file.csv',sep=',')
```

I don't see any problems

Comment: Ben, the problem starts when you try to apply the function to the uploaded data ('test_file.csv as df). In my envi this code fails  >>>output = df_cleaned.groupby('group', 
            as_index=False).words.apply(counts).reset_index(drop=True)<<< for df uploaded from csv.

Comment: From your comment I'm not able to understand what is failing. Perhaps you could reword your question and code samples to clarify what you're experiencing? If you have a notebook that reproduces the issue, that would be useful.

Comment: I found the solution. The problem was generated by csv read. It losses a tuple from initial database and return an array of list of lists. I have modified the code by adding 'word_tokenize' to the command: '...ngrams(word_tokenize(row), 3)'. I do not fully udnerstand why it works the way it works, but the problem is gone. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The problem will arise when you apply this code to df: output = df.groupby('group', as_index=False).words.apply(counts).reset_index(drop=True)   It disappears when the ngram function gets modified by adding 'word_tokenize' and looks like this: 'ngram_list = [pair for row in s for pair in ngrams(word_tokenize(row), 3)]''